# How to push data to Object on nested function

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, https

```
const http = require('https');

exports.ip = async (req, res) => {
    const ip = req.body.ip;
    const ip_list = ip.trim().split(' ');
    const count = ip_list.length;
    var execution_count = 0;
    var success = {}; //--------------->**Object**
    success.result = []; // <-------
    const name = 'lenin royal'
    ip_list.map((r) => {
        execution_count = execution_count + 1
        const options = {
            method: 'GET',
            hostname: 'www.test.com',
            port: null,
            path: `/api/v3/object/${r}`,
            headers: {
                accept: 'application/json',
                'x-apikey': '###########'
            }
        };
        const request = http.request(options, function (response) {
            const chunks = [];
            const l = [];
            response.on('data', function (chunk) {
                chunks.push(chunk);
            });

            response.on('end', function () {
                body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
                var q = JSON.parse(body.toString()); --------->// variable **q**
                success.result.push(q) -----------> // I want to push this q variable to success
            });
            
        });
        console.log(success)
        if (execution_count == count) {
            res.send(success)
        }
    })

}
```

Hi, I am doing an automation-like project my requirement is I will to make multiple API calls and store all data in one object In this case I'm using **success** as an object I'm using **https** for API fetching, and if I make one API request the response I will store in variable **q** I need to store my data to the Object so I am using **sucess.result.push(q)**. if this works then I can able to make multiple API calls and store them on the Object and send them as one response.

Comment: i am not sure but i think this is due to `async` nature of the operation you are trying to perform.

Comment: Use promises or async/await to wait for all the API calls to complete before calling `res.send()`

Comment: Please provide more details about what is preventing you from doing what you want. Do you get an exception? If so, show a stack trace.

Comment: After removing the async is also not working, Any other ideas, please?

Comment: The main problem is I can't able to push the data to success.result

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `.map` for async operations, use for loops.

```
for i = 0; i < ip_list.length; i++ {
  //do your stuff here.
}
```

You also won't need `execution_count = execution_count + 1` and `execution_count === count` when u use for loops like example given.

If you really need to use `.map`, use it together with `Promise.all`

Following example I am using [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch)

```
exports.ip = async (req, res) => {
    const ip = req.body.ip;
    const ip_list = ip.trim().split(' ');

    const results = await Promise.all(ip_list.map((r) => fetch(`https://www.test.com/api/v3/object/${r}`, {
           headers: {
                accept: 'application/json',
                'x-apikey': '###########'
           }
      }).then(res => res.json())
    ))

    res.send({ results })
}
```

Comment: Thanks,But I change the map function to loop and I also remove those execution_count = execution_count + 1 but I can't able push the q variable to the Object, Can you please give any idea?

Comment: updated with proper answer with Promise.all